# Asp.Net Optimization bundling failing. No query string

Tags: asp.net, http, optimization, umbraco

We are using the bundling and minification functionality in 4.5 to compress CSS and JS on our site. We have used it before and it works fine. Locally it outputs links as follows:

```
<link href="/minifiedCssHead?v=eNSlT3AA1_wMazOm7q246Ju_trcQgzpT9FIcgle6NwE1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Move it to the live server and it just generates:

```
<link href="/minifiedCssHead" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

We are baffled as to why it won't even generate the querystring. Let alone the file. This is all running alongside Umbraco but that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Apologies if this is a trivial question to ask, but I assume you've checked the application pool .net version for both environments, all other IIS settings, and made sure file permissions are the same across both environments as well?

Comment: I'm not sure it's supposed to render a random querystring by default

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem intermittently when I put new versions of the script and style files on the web server. Recycling the Application Pool solves it for me. This can be done either using the IIS manager or from the command line

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:YourAppPool
```